# opening a file with a user given name (fopen in c)

Tags: c, fopen

I need to get a user name from a user and open a file with his name if it already exists.
if the file doesn't exist I need to create one.
now I don't really know how to do it. (in c)

is this code line legal?

```
fopen("%s.txt", "r+", username);
```

and if not what alternatives do I have?
maybe there is a better way to do it?

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hahaha, no. First you have to `sprintf`  the value of `username` into an appropriate buffer, then use that buffer as input to `fopen` (i.e., you cannot combine these two operations into one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
char* ext = ".txt";
char* filename = malloc(strlen(username) + strlen(ext) + 1);
sprintf(filename, "%s%s", username, ext);
FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r+");
free(filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

You had right idea but did not use correct function to do it.

```
char *filename = malloc(strlen(username) + strlen(".txt")+1);

if (filename) {
  sprintf(filename, "%s.txt", username);
  fopen(filename, "r+");
}
```